# How to access Downloads folder in taiko automation

Tags: automation, automated-tests, getgauge

I want to verify whether file is downloaded or not after clicking download link.
I am using taiko for automating this task.
I tried to open recent downloads in browser by using these taiko commands `goto("chrome://downloads/")`
and `press(['Control','J'])` but both did't work.
Is there any other method to do the same task.And i want know why above commands are not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [example](https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/blob/master/examples/02-file_download.js)

You need to first set the download path:

```
// client function is imported from taiko
await client().send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: downloadPath,
});
```

You then need to download your file (trigger the action that results in the file getting downloaded - the example uses a `click` action. And then, after a suitable time has elapsed, you will check the download path that you registered earlier for existence of the file:

```
expect(path.join(downloadPath, 'foo.txt')).to.exist;
```

Comment: may i know why your using `expect(path.join(downloadPath, 'foo.txt')).to.exist;` 
I tried to check file existence by using if statement but condition become true even if file was not present

Comment: I followed the example in the reference, but in general, that code is checking whether that path exists or not